# How to concatenate files split by round robin?

Tags: linux, unix, split, paste, cat

I split a file using `split -n r/12 file`, now how do I concatenate these 12 files? I've tried `cat <files>` and `paste <files>`, but after using diff, whole file was different from the original.

How do I concatenate these 12 files so that cmp/diff will show no differences? Any special arguments for paste/cat to use?

Comment: If you're still interested, I have a suggestion for [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75214248/16343464)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is round robin splitting an absolute requirement? If not you might just split into sections:

```
$split --number=12 file
```

This creates 12 files:

```
$ ls x*
xaa xab xac xad xae xaf xag xah xai xaj xak xal
```

Now you can concat without any difference:

```
$cat x* > file.new

$diff file file.new
```

But if there is no way around the round robin requirement I would create a bash script - not pretty. Just providing a pseudocode

Something like:

```
Create working directory
Copy all x* files into working directory
Change to working directory
Touch new concatenated file

While all x* files are not empty
  Iterate over files in alpha order
     Remove the first line in file
     Append the line to the new concatenated file
```